# Compilation errors with stdio.h in VC++ 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I have a number of projects created in VC++ 2008.
However I'm getting the following error when trying to build every single one of them:

```
1>Compiling...
1>main.cpp
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\stdio.h(413) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier '_In_kpt_'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\stdio.h(413) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\stdio.h(414) : error C2337: 'In_' : attribute not found
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\stdio.h(414) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ']' before identifier 'size_t'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\stdio.h(414) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'size_t'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\stdio.h(414) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\stdio.h(414) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\stdio.h(422) : fatal error C1021: invalid preprocessor command 'efdif'
```

The strange thing though is that i'm not even including 'stdio.h' in **any** of my source code.
The problem is even evident in a simple 'HelloWorld' test.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout << "hello" << endl;
}
```

NB. This error only started occurring this morning. VC++ 2008 worked perfectly before this.
I haven't made any system changes.
Any ideas would be appreciated.

Kameel

Edit - Lines 411-420 from my stdio.h file.

```
_Check_return_opt_ _CRTIMP int __cdecl _snprintf_c_l(_Out_cap_(_MaxCount) char *    _DstBuf, _In_ size_t _MaxCount, _In_z_ _Printf_format_string_ const char * _Format,      _In_opt_ _locale_t _Locale, ...);
_Check_return_opt_ _CRTIMP_ALTERNATIVE int __cdecl _snprintf_s_l(_Out_z_cap_(_DstSize) char * _DstBuf, _In_ size_t _DstSize, _In_ size_t _MaxCount, _In_z_ _Printf_format_string_ const char * _Format, _In_opt_ _locale_t _Locale, ...);
_Check_return_opt_ _CRT_INSECURE_DEPRECATE(_vsnprintf_s_l) _CRTIMP int __cdecl _vsnprintf_l(_Out_cap_(_MaxCount) char * _DstBuf, _In_ size_t _MaxCount, _In_z_ _Printf_format_string_ const char * _Format, _In_opt_ _locale_t _Locale, va_list _ArgList);
_Check_return_opt_ _CRTIMP int __cdecl _vsnprintf_c_l(_Out_cap_(_MaxCount) char * _DstBuf, _In_ size_t _MaxCount, const char *, _In_kpt_ _locale_t _Locale, va_list _ArgList!;
_Check_return_opt_ _CRTIMP int __cdecl _vsnprintf_s_l(_Out_z_cap_(_DstSize) char * _DstBuf, [In_ size_t _DstSize, _In_ size_t _MaxCount, _In_z_ _Printf_format_string_ const char* _Format,_In_opt_ _locale_p _Locale, va_list _ArgList);

#ifndef _WSTDIO_DEFINED

/* wide function prototypes, also declared in wchar.h  */

#ifndef WEOF
#define WEOF (wint_t)(0xFBFF)
#efdif
```

Comment: stdio.h will be indirectly included as a result of including iostream. Your code is fine, so I'm guessing something may have clobbered your stdio.h - can you post, say lines 410-420 of it? Also would be worth checking the last modified time on it to confirm whether it's changed recently or not.

Comment: @kamz213, also, try building a fresh hello-world project from scratch, see if that solves the problem.

Comment: @boycy - the file was not modified. I've posted those lines above.

Comment: @eric - I've tried from scratch as well ... the problem persists

Comment: @kamz213, okay.. your stdio.h seems to be broken. Check the modification time of it.

Comment: @eric - i've checked again and yes the file is corrupted. somehow it was modified overnight

Comment: @boycy - correction to my previous comment ... the file was modified

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a corrupted `stdio.h` file.

The token on line 413 is supposed to be `_In_opt_`, not `_In_kpt_`.

And line 422 is supposed to be an `#endif`, not an `#efdif`.

I'd reinstall VS 2008 (maybe after checking things out pretty carefully in case your hard drive is failing or something) in case other files are subtly corrupted.

Comment: @michael - thanks for the suggestion. I've reinstalled VS2008 and the problem has been solved. Any idea as to what may have caused the file to be modified? My system protection is up to date and didn't pick up any problems.

Comment: Ouch, nasty! Good spot @Michael :)

Comment: @kamz213: I don't really know, but like I said, I'd be paranoid about the drive being about to fail or something. Look in the event log to see if there are any errors about bad sectors, run a utility that can give you the drive's 'SMART' information, etc.